# How to use a ViewComponent inside an already rendered ViewComponent?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, .net-6.0

On my page I have the following:

```
@if (Model.Questionnaire != null)
{
    <div class="w-100 questionnaire">
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("QuestionsPage", Model.Questionnaire)
    </div>
}
```

Inside of the template for the QuestionsPage component, I'm similarly loading another component:

```
@if (Model.Questionnaire.Sections.Any(x => x.ParentId == _section.Id))
{
    foreach (var s in Model.Questionnaire.Sections.Where(x => x.ParentId == _section.Id))
    {
        <section id="@s.Id" class="section d-none" data-parent="@_section.Id">
            <h4>@s.Name</h4>
            <p>@s.Description</p>

            @await Component.InvokeAsync("Questions", _section.Questions)
        </section>
    }
}
```

Problem I'm noticing is that the "Questions" component isn't rendering. Both ViewComponents are invoked with the correct data for their models and in exactly the same way.

Is it even possible to invoke a ViewComponent as a child inside of another ViewComponent and if it is, how does one do it?

#### Additional info:

The QuestionsViewComponent is invoked as follows:

```
namespace FooPortal.ViewComponents
{
    public class QuestionsViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        public IViewComponentResult Invoke(List<QuestionnaireQuestionViewmodel> questions)
        {
            return View(questions);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my folder structure in the app specifically including the Components

EDIT

The Component does actually load correctly with the given structure/processing.

The problem is the model data isn't loading into it.

[image]

Comment: Did you have a chance to debug it? Does it throw any error? Either of the components is not displaying?